# Multiple Comparisons testing and Dunn's Test

Tags: nonparametric, dunn-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have 8 different groups of individuals, each with a pre- and post-treatment measurement.  The data are non-normal, so I used a Jonckheere-Terpstra test to test for an ordered alternative and rejected the null.  I'd like to report p-values for the comparison of pre-treatment means to post-treatment means, and I used a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test for each age group.  However, now I realize that this may not be allowed without doing a multiple comparisons test to determine which groups are significantly different.  I used Dunn's test to verify that there is a significant difference between groups 4 and 5 and between 5 and 6.  What does this mean for when I can perform Wilcoxon Signed-Rank to compare pre-test to post-test?  Can I only do the comparisons for these two pairs?  Can I compare the other groups?

Comment: I've been doing some more research, and it looks as though doing Jonckheere-Terpstra tests on both pre- and post-treatment data would be incorrect.  A Friedman test might be appropriate since it seems to be the non-parametric equivalent of repeated measures ANOVA.  Can anyone who understands better confirm this?  If so, would I need to perform one Friedman test to test for effect of age, and another to test for effect of pre/post-measurement?  Or just do the Friedman test for age, do a multiple comparisons test, and then do separate Wilcoxon Signed-Rank tests on those groups with differences?

Comment: Jonckheere-Terpstra is the ordered-alternatives version of kruskal-Wallis (one-way anova-like situation). There are similar ordered-alternative versions corresponding to Friedman as well (Page's test, one of the Match tests). If you still have an ordered alternatives, you shouldn't ignore that fact.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169419/why-bother-looking-at-an-omnibus-anova-when-i-have-a-priori-hypotheses-about-gro/169452#169452